How do two distinct, but possibly related, formulas each give rise to OEIS A067611?
BACKGROUND: The Sieve of Sundaram effectively identifies composite odd numbers, relying on the property that the odd numbers (i.e. numbers having no factors of $2$) are closed under multiplication. $2m+1$ is composite if it can be expressed as $2m+1=(2x+1)(2y+1)$ for $x,y\in \mathbb Z^+$. Simplifying, $2m+1$ is composite if $m$ has the form $2xy+x+y$. Note that if $xy=0$, the trivial factorization $2m+1=1\cdot (2m+1)$ can be obtained, justifying the constraint $xy>0$.
Numbers of the form $6m\pm 1$ (i.e. numbers having no factors of either $2$ or $3$) are similarly closed under multiplication, and thus can be analyzed using Sundaram-like logic. The numbers $6m-1$ and $6m+1$ contain at least one composite member iff $6m\pm 1=(6x\pm 1)(6y\pm 1)$, again with the constraint $x,y\in \mathbb Z^+$. This equation simplifies to $m=6xy\pm x\pm y$. Numbers of this form are given in OEIS A067611, and are the numbers $m$ such that $6m\pm 1$ is not a twin prime pair. The complementary set of numbers $m$ such that $6m\pm 1$ is a twin prime pair is given in OEIS A002822
A NEW FORMULA: Numbers of the form $36m^2-1$ are semiprimes iff they have no proper factors other than $6m-1$ and $6m+1$, that is, they are the product of a twin prime pair. Applying the logic of Sundaram, we can look for positive integers $a,b\in \mathbb Z^+$ such that $36m^2-1=(6(m-a)\pm 1)(6(m+b)\mp 1)$ to determine whether $36m^2-1$ is a semiprime. Solving the equation for $m$, we obtain
$$m=\frac{6ab\pm (a+b)}{6(b-a)}$$
Although $f(a,b)=\frac{6ab\pm (a+b)}{6(b-a)}$ returns many non-integer values, we are interested only in positive integer values it returns as potential proper values of $m$. To this end, we note that the denominator requires that $b>a$, and the factor of $6$ in the denominator requires that $b\equiv -a \bmod 6$ to render the entire numerator divisible by $6$. Further, it is observed that when $b=6a^2-a$, then $f(a,b)=a$. In the case that $a=m$ and $b=6m^2-m$, we obtain the trivial factorization of $36m^2-1=1\cdot (36m^2-1)$. To avoid this, we require $0<a<b<6a^2-a$ as the pertinent ranges of $a,b$. Within those ranges, it is observed that as $b$ increases, $f(a,b)$ approaches, but does not reach, $a$ from above. This means that the integer candidates that $f(a,b)$ returns for $m$ are always larger than $a$ itself, which ensures that any candidate factor $6(m-a)\pm 1$ will be larger than $1$.
EMPIRICAL PERFORMANCE: Hand computation using values of $a$ from $1$ to $30$, and appropriate values of $b$, the function $f(a,b)$ generated every member of OEIS A067611 up to $36$ and several larger integers, all of which are included in OEIS A067611. It did not generate any integers that are not in OEIS A067611. Although the computational sample is small in absolute terms, together with the logic of its derivation, it affords confidence that this new formula will generate the same set of integers as does $m=6xy\pm x\pm y$, to wit OEIS A067611.
OBSERVATION: Both $g(x,y)=6xy\pm x\pm y$ and $f(a,b)=\frac{6ab\pm (a+b)}{6(b-a)}$ (subject to appropriate conditions) give rise to every member of, and only to members of, OEIS A067611. Note, however, that the numerator of $f(a,b)$, with or without the limitations that it must be evenly divisible by $6(b-a)$, $0<a<b<6a^2-a$ and $b\equiv -a \bmod 6$, has a form which is included within $g(a,b)$. Thus, there is a subset of OEIS A067611 which contains enough information (if that is the correct way to present the thought) to give rise to the entirety of OEIS A067611.
QUESTIONS: The big question for me is: Why does this work this way in this particular instance? Two distinct formulas, one of which contains a term related to the second formula, give rise to the same set of integers. I have been unable to construct an algebraic manipulation or other explanation for why this should be the case. The lesser questions are: Does this kind of relationship have precedents? Are there other (non-trivial) examples of sets wherein an algebraic manipulation of a subset of members of a set can generate every member without generating any non-members?
